# open .dat database file in android

Tags: android, database

I have downloaded an .apk file and decompiled it. I want the database.
I have found data base in .dat format but in code it uses sqlite code to query from it.
How can I get the data in .dat file

Answer (score 0):

Database is created on first launch of app. It's not in apk file.

So launch app, and check files in `/data/data/apppackagename/databases/`
(replace apppackagename by the real app package)